# Quick start "complex" command from within PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, alias

Is it possible to run a "complex" PowerShell commands from within PowerShell using an alias?

To give you an example I would like to replace the command `Get-VpnConnection -name "VPNname"` via a (non reserved) one-word-command e.g. `vpn` via an alias? Unfortunately `set-Alias vpn "Get-VpnConnection -name VPNname"` does not work, nor does `set-Alias vpn Get-VpnConnection -name "VPNname"` (note the different position of the first quotation mark).

So far my "workaround" is to save the command as a script file in PowerShells "start-up directory" (in my case `C:\Users\username`) and run `.\vpn.ps1` via an alias. I create the alias using `set-Alias vpn ".\script_vpncheck.ps1"`. Is there a direct way to do it (without creating a script file)?

Follow-up question: In case this is not possible I would like to initialize the aliases using a script file e.g. via `.\script.ps1` (Note: I don't need to store them permanently). Unfortunately this does not work. The file seems to be executed but the aliases don't work. Any idea why?

Comment: If the alias does not exist, then you must create it. You can create an alias in your function or after using the alias cmdlet.

Comment: @postanote I know, currently I'm creating the aliases via the script file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the alias to the [profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7)

- Open the profile from PowerShell by running `notepad $PROFILE` (or use any favorite editor of yours)
- Enter the commands you like to run into that file and save (for example `Set-Alias`)
- Restart PowerShell or source the newly updated profile by running `. $PROFILE`

The profile is just exactly as `.bashrc` in bash which will be run when the shell is started. Besides aliases you can also write [functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7) for more complex things. They'll be available after PowerShell starts

```
function vpn($url) { Get-VpnConnection -name $url }
Set-Alias -Name vpn -Value Get-VpnConnection
```

You can't set alias for commands with arguments so you must create a function in that case

The reason your ps1 file doesn't work is because it's run in the *subshell* and when the subshell closes, everything will be cleared including the new aliases. You must [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7) the script using the dot source operator `.` (similar to `.` in bash) to run it in the current shell

```
. .\script.ps1
```

But instead of sourcing that everytime you want the alias, just do it permanently in the profile as above

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind creating them manually at the beginning of the session, but I think I will try store a permanent alias for starting the alias-script.

Comment: In regards to my main question, is it possible to create the alias without the script? Doing it via `set-Alias vpn "Get-VpnConnection -name VPNname"` doesn't work. (I updated the question).

Comment: @Albin alias just replaces the cmdlet name, since you have arguments you need to use a function instead: `function vpn { Get-VpnConnection -name VPNname }`

Comment: that's what I was looking for, thanks! And using `.` + F8 works like a charm to load the functions/aliases (after I used `. .\script__.ps1` for the first time : )

Answer (score 1):

Aliases aren't intended to take parameters. From the `about_aliases` help topic:

> ALTERNATE NAMES FOR COMMANDS WITH PARAMETERS
>
> You can assign an alias to a cmdlet, script, function, or executable
> file. You cannot assign an alias to a command and its parameters. For
> example, you can assign an alias to the Get-Eventlog cmdlet, but you
> cannot assign an alias to the Get-Eventlog -LogName System command.
>
> You can create a function that includes the command. To create a
> function, type the word "function" followed by a name for the
> function. Type the command, and enclose it in braces ({}).
>
> For example, the following command creates the syslog function. This
> function represents the Get-Eventlog -LogName System command:
>
> ```
> function Get-SystemEventlog {Get-Eventlog -LogName System}
> Set-Alias -Name syslog -Value Get-SystemEventlog
> ```
>
> You can now type "syslog" instead of the command. And, you can create
> aliases for the new function.

But you don't need a seperate script file. You can define a simple function and add it to your profile with the following code:

```
'Function vpn { Get-VpnConnection -name VPNname }' | Add-Content $PROFILE
```

The command `vpn` will be available in all **PowerShell** sessions from that point on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, phuclv already answered this in the comments, but I'll leave a +1 anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was just scanning the lead of the other answer & it didn't seem to explicitly say "an alias won't work" right off the bat. I'm visually impaired & it's easier for me to type than to read. LOL